# If you put some air onto the moon, is it possible to talk within the region that the air is present in?

Tags: acoustics, vacuum, gas

So uhhh lets say there is some air, you've just put it onto the surface of the moon. Question being, if you are present within the mass of the air, can you listen to others and talk to them within the space that the air occupies?

Comment: The short answer is yes. How much air you need and how long it will stay there is another matter.

Comment: It works if you put air in space, say in the space station. The last time this experiment was tried on the moon was when the last astronauts visited. But perhaps you are thinking of air not confined in a container?

Answer (score 1):

If you release some compressed air on the surface of the moon, the air zooms away in all directions at high speed because there's nothing present to slow it down, and quickly dissipates into space because the moon's gravity is too weak to hold in place. All this happens in an instant, after which there's no air left there through which you could walk and talk without a space suit.